# Variadic macro in VS2013 not valid

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to compile the example from [QtSocketIO](https://github.com/KurtPattyn/QtSocketIo) called EchoClient.

However when I try to compile using MSVC2013, I get the following error in the `echoclient.cpp`

> 1>  echoclient.cpp
>
> 1>echoclient.cpp(7): error C2010: '.' : unexpected in macro formal parameter list

The code looks like this where I have put as comments the errors in each line

```
#include "echoclient.h"
#include "qsocketioclient.h"
#include <QtCore/QJsonObject>
#include <QtCore/QJsonArray>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
    
#define function(args...) [=](args)   // Error expected a ')'

void EchoClient::connected(QString endpoint)
{
    qDebug() << "Connected to endpoint" << endpoint;
    m_client.emitMessage("event with 2 arguments", 
                         QVariantList() << 1 << QStringLiteral("Hello socket.io"),
                         function(QJsonArray returnValue) {  // Error expected an expression
        qDebug() << "Got reply from event with 2 arguments:" << returnValue;
    });
    m_client.emitMessage("event with a json object",
                         QVariantMap({ {"number", 1}, { QStringLiteral("message"), 
                         QStringLiteral("Hello socket.io")}}),
                         function(QJsonArray returnValue) { // Error expected an expression
        qDebug() << "Got reply from event with a json object:" << returnValue;
    });
    m_client.on("event from server", function(QJsonArray data) { // Error expected an expression
        qDebug() << "Got event from server with data" << data;
    });
}
```

Can someone explain to me what does that macro is doing? Is there a way to solve the error?

Comment: The macro seems to just give a more familiar form to lambdas. I'm not sure if VS2013 supports lambdas though, that is a C++11 feature.

Comment: At a guess, you have a problem with the syntax.  Change args... to ... and args to __VA_ARGS__.  @triple_r VS2013 supports lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro is making a lambda look sort of like an ordinary function declaration. The reason it doesn't work is because, as mentioned in the comments, `#define function(args...) [=](args)` isn't correct. Changing it to `#define function(...) [=](__VA_ARGS__)` will work.